# OR'ing two INNER JOIN's in MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Is it possible to OR two separate INNER JOIN's so that the result set contains data from either of the two INNER JOIN's? For instance, is the following possible in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
(INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name)
OR
(INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.column_name=table3.column_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant do this way, one way is to use union

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
union
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.column_name=table3.column_name
```

Comment: As per the question  `so that the result set contains data from either of the two INNER JOIN`, so union should do the job here

Comment: Ahh this is correct, the use of "or" in the sample threw me off.

Comment: Would union still work if say I wanted only the 10 most recent results?

Comment: you can order and limit the result, by selecting from the union

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.column_name=table3.column_name
```

As described [at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html), `UNION` combines the results of several selects.

Answer (score 0):

you need use `where`

```
 select * from table1 
where

  (table1.column_name = (select table2.column_name from table2 inner join table1.column_name as  on table1.column_name = table2.column_name)) 

OR

  (table1.column_name = (select table3.column_name from table3   inner join table1.column_name as  on table1.column_name = table3.column_name))
```

work perfect here!